# change h6 with variable content

Tags: javascript, html

i managed to get a div created for each content of "var nameModTypes", now what i need to achieve is how to put "let nombre" in the first H6 that is created in div.innerHTML . Any idea how I could achieve it?

That is my javascript code:

```js
var nameModTypes = [ 
    {"name": "spoilers" , "num": 0},
    {"name": "frontBumper" , "num": 1},
];
function CrearModTypeDiv(){
    for (var i = 0; i < nameModTypes.length; i++){
        let nombre = nameModTypes[i].name; 
        const div = document.createElement('div');

    div.className = 'modType panel';

    div.innerHTML = `
                    <div class="col s12 panel-title">
                        <h6></h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s12 panel-bottom">
                        <div class="col s6 panel-col">
                            <h6 class="grey-text text-lighten-3 panel-label">
                                <span id= "1" class="total-number"></span>
                            </h6>
                            <button class="button-left">
                                <i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i>
                            </button>
                            <input class="input-number" type="number" value="0">
                            <button class="button-right">
                                <i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `;

    document.getElementById('modTypeContainer').appendChild(div);

    };
};
```

Comment: `<h6> ${nombre} </h6>`

Comment: You're already using a template string for `.innerHTML`. Grab a documentation for it and you will find the solution - [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: since you are using backticks (``) then you can use ${} to assign your variable in your html string.
for example:
div.innerhtml = 

your html code

<h6>${nombre}</h6>



other html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using template literals, just put the variable you want to parse between ${}

`<h6>${nombre}</h6>`

More info about template literals here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals